# R arrow json reader calls notimplemented function

Tags: r, json, apache-arrow

I'm trying to use the arrow json reader in R:

```
library(arrow)
read_json_arrow("http://stats.oecd.org/sdmx-json/data/QNA/all/all?startTime=2009-Q1&endTime=2009-Q4")
```

It gives the error:

```
Error: NotImplemented: Call to R (readBin() on R connection) from a non-R thread from an unsupported context
```

The json file seems fine, as this works:

```
library("rjson")
fromJSON("http://stats.oecd.org/sdmx-json/data/QNA/all/all?startTime=2009-Q1&endTime=2009-Q4")
```

Comment: `read_json_arrow()` only reads newline-delimited json (ndjson) where each line is a row in the resulting dataframe; see [the docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/read_json_arrow.html). If you try to read normal json with no newlines with it, it's assuming everything is one row, and things go wrong.

Comment: The actual error message here is caused by a bug which was fixed in the dev version of Arrow, and relates to reading in files from a URL, but as @alistaire has said above, it won't work with the file in question anyway as it's not newline-delimited JSON.